# Ext JS - Dynamically adding panel inside a panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, sencha-architect

I am kind of stuck in one of the requirements.

From my Ajax request, I get following XML back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rowsets Version="15.0 SP4 Patch 4 (Jun 3, 2015)" StartDate="2015-08-28T22:19:43" EndDate="2015-08-28T23:19:43" DateCreated="2015-08-28T23:19:43" CachedTime="">
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <ID_PART>23</ID_PART>
            <DS_PART>23 - MAIN</DS_PART>
            <DS_MATERIAL>Lubricant (100-1111)</DS_MATERIAL>
            <DS_STATUS>Not-Running</DS_STATUS>
            <ID_MACHINE>1</ID_MACHINE>
            <DS_MACHINE>A - TOP</DS_MACHINE>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <ID_PART>24</ID_PART>
            <DS_PART>24 - MAIN</DS_PART>
            <DS_MATERIAL>OLOA 5702-2222</DS_MATERIAL>
            <DS_STATUS>Not-Running</DS_STATUS>
            <ID_MACHINE>1</ID_MACHINE>
            <DS_MACHINE>A - TOP</DS_MACHINE>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <ID_PART>25</ID_PART>
            <DS_PART>25 - OVER</DS_PART>
            <DS_MATERIAL>GX CART (311-6911)</DS_MATERIAL>
            <DS_STATUS>Producing</DS_STATUS>
            <ID_MACHINE>1</ID_MACHINE>
            <DS_MACHINE>A - TOP</DS_MACHINE>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <ID_PART>29</ID_PART>
            <DS_PART>29 - MAIN</DS_PART>
            <DS_MATERIAL>CARTRIDGE (300-6)</DS_MATERIAL>
            <DS_STATUS>Producing</DS_STATUS>
            <ID_MACHINE>2</ID_MACHINE>
            <DS_MACHINE>B - TOP</DS_MACHINE>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <ID_PART>30</ID_PART>
            <DS_PART>30 - MAIN</DS_PART>
            <DS_MATERIAL>BODY GX (300-1)</DS_MATERIAL>
            <DS_STATUS>Producing</DS_STATUS>
            <ID_MACHINE>2</ID_MACHINE>
            <DS_MACHINE>B - TOP</DS_MACHINE>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <ID_PART>37</ID_PART>
            <DS_PART>37 - VALVE</DS_PART>
            <DS_MATERIAL>LAB 100-111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <DS_STATUS>Not-Running</DS_STATUS>
            <ID_MACHINE>3</ID_MACHINE>
            <DS_MACHINE>E - TOP</DS_MACHINE>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <ID_PART>39</ID_PART>
            <DS_PART>39 - CAP</DS_PART>
            <DS_MATERIAL>LAB 222-111</DS_MATERIAL>
            <DS_STATUS>Not-Running</DS_STATUS>
            <ID_MACHINE>3</ID_MACHINE>
            <DS_MACHINE>E - TOP</DS_MACHINE>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <ID_PART>45</ID_PART>
            <DS_PART>45 - CAP</DS_PART>
            <DS_MATERIAL>CHemical (111-2222)</DS_MATERIAL>
            <DS_STATUS>Not-Running</DS_STATUS>
            <ID_MACHINE>5</ID_MACHINE>
            <DS_MACHINE>A - BOTTOM</DS_MACHINE>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <ID_PART>40</ID_PART>
            <DS_PART>40 - CAP</DS_PART>
            <DS_MATERIAL>OLOA Bulk (222-3333)</DS_MATERIAL>
            <DS_STATUS>Not-Running</DS_STATUS>
            <ID_MACHINE>5</ID_MACHINE>
            <DS_MACHINE>A - BOTTOM</DS_MACHINE>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Now, For each ID_MACHINE I want a panel which has title as DS_MACHINE. Inside that panel, I need to add all of the ID_PART associated with that ID_MACHINE - mainly showing DS_PART as main header of inside panel and inside that DS_MATERIAL as displayfield , DS_STATUS as displayfield.

In a nutshell,

```
| A - TOP | --> Main Machine Panel
      |23 - MAIN| --> Part Panel
          Not-Running   Lubricant (100-1111)
      |24 - MAIN| ---> PArt Panel
          Not-Running  OLOA 5702-222
      |25 - OVER| ---> PArt Panel
          Producing  GX CART (311-6911)

| B - TOP | --> Main MAchine Panel
      || --> part panel
      || ---> part panel
so on ...
```

My controller looks like following:

```
loadMachinePanel : function(panel) {
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/XMII/Illuminator',
    method: 'GET',

    success: function(response) {

        var rows = response.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Row');

        for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

        var machineid= rows[i].childNodes[4].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var machinename= rows[i].childNodes[5].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var partid = rows[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var partname = rows[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var statusname = rows[i].childNodes[3].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var matname= rows[i].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


            panel.add({
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: machinename,
                border: true,
                height: 350,
                padding: '3 0 3 0',
                bodyPadding: 3,
                margin:15,
                titleAlign:'center',
                id: 'MainPanel' + machineid,
                style: 'cursor: pointer;',

                items: [
                {

                xtype: 'panel',
                title: partname,
                titleAlign:'center',
                height: 108,
                padding: '3 0 3 0',
                bodyPadding: 3,
                margin:10,
                layout: 'hbox',
                id: 'PartPanel' + partid,
                border: true,
                style: 'cursor:pointer;',


                            items: [

                              {
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                flex: 1,
                                items: [{
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    value: 'STATUS'
                                        },{
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    value: statusname
                                            }]
                                }

                {
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                flex: 1,
                                items: [{
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    value: 'Product Running'
                                        },{
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    value: matname
                                            }]
                                }

                               ]
            }]
        });


        }
        panel.doLayout();
    },

    params: {
        'QueryTemplate': 'FOlderName/Dashboard/ManagementMachineInfoSelect',
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    }
});
}
```

Somehow this code creates duplicate panels and messes up the page. Not sure this is the right way to do it.

Can anyone please correct it or give better solution?

Thanks !

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)?

Comment: Cant you use iframes.. That is generally easier. Just saying.